# For new linux users, what is an easy way to get the login name in python?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, operating-system

I'm using ubuntu mate on raspberry pi 3b. Is there an easy way to do something similar to:

```
import os
name = os.getlogin()
print(name)
```

(from windows)? When I try to use this on linux, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "(this is a less than sign)pyshell#3(this is a greater than sign)", line 1, in <module>

print(os.getlogin())
OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Comment: Luckily the documentation is helpful here: "For most purposes, it is more useful to use getpass.getuser() ..."

Comment: Please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54167704/edit) your question to explain *why* do you need a *login name***. Smells like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. I don't understand for what kind of application such a name is really needed (on Unix, the  `uid` is a more natural way of thinking)

Comment: Without motivation, **your question is unclear.** You don't define what is the login name and why you need it. What should your program do if it cannot find a login name? Or if it find different ones (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54167834/841108)) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to **define what is the "login name"** (and *why* you need it). In the details it is not that simple (and I am not exactly sure that you understand what it is exactly, even on Windows, which I don't know). Notice that [`os.getlogin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=getlogin#os.getlogin) is *documented* to use the [controlling terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface) (read more about these in [the TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/),  [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html), [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html)) and in some cases (e.g. a [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) job, a remote command started thru `ssh`, etc...) you don't have any.

You could use some environment variable. See [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) (and find its Python equivalent, probably [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=dup2#os.environ)). In most cases (in some interactive session), both `USER` and `LOGNAME` environment variables would give you some "login name". In pathological cases, they could be missing or different (or incorrect, think of [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) programs). Python has [`getpass.getuser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html?highlight=getuser#getpass.getuser)

Then, read about [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html). You then know that every process has its uid (see [getuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html) and `geteuid`). That [uid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) is a number (a probable equivalent on Windows would be the [SID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier)). From that number you might get a "login name" using [getpwuid(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3.html), in Python [pwd.getpwuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pwd.html#pwd.getpwuid)

In very rare pathological cases, you might even have a process with some uid which has no "login name" (this could, for example, happen with an old process running in a uid that you have deleted from your `/etc/passwd`, see [passwd(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html))

In pathological cases, `USER` & `LOGNAME` environment variables, and `getuid` / `geteuid` followed by `getpwuid` could give *different* "login names", then you have to decide which one you want (that is equivalent to *exactly* define what "login name" means to  you).

You should read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) to learn more about Linux programming, and adapt the knowledge you get from there (ALP explains things from a C API point of view) to Python.

If you need a [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory), the common wisdom is to use the `HOME` environment variable (but again, you might have pathological cases where it is unset or wrong; in such rare cases, you need to define what you really want.).

PS. On Unix systems, I don't understand why you need a login *name* in general. The common idiom is to reason in terms of [uid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier).

Answer (score 1):

> `os.environ` is a dictionary, which contains various type of environment variable. Here `USERNAME`, `LOGNAME`, `USER` etc are system-state environment variable. So according to the operating system and type of current user, we can find those environment variables.
>   When we login as a normal user in `Ubuntu`, we have all `USERNAME`, `LOGNAME` and `USER` in system-state environment variable but when we login as a `root` user we have `USER` and `LOGNAME` in system-state environment variable.
>   Please look at the below code for normal user in `Ubuntu`.

```
import os
# From os.environ, you can read USERNAME and LOGNAME 
os.environ['USERNAME']
os.environ['LOGNAME']
```

Comment: It would be better to provide some explanation in English in that answer

Comment: Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch, going forward surely I will follow it. For now, as per your advice I edited my answer.